# How to use microservices in Spring MVC

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-mvc

Good evening everyone!

Currently, we are using Spring MVC, where View is represented by JSP files. In most cases, we do not use AJAX to retrieve the data from the server.As far as I know, a page generates on the server side. My boss assigned a task for me to move to React JS. Apparently, to get the data, I will have to make Ajax calls. We cannot touch the back-end.
At the same time, my co-workers mentioned a fresh feature called "Microservices". I have never used that technology before. I did some research and as I understood, a microservice is small component which does only one(or couple) actions. I think, the microservice component will be placed between View and Model. 
Something like that: View(React) ---> Microservice ---> Controller --> Model.

Basically, View will make AJAX call to the microservice which will receive the right data from Controller and Model.

I explained as I understood. Thank you for your time. Any help or advice will be in asset.

Comment: I don't think microservice solves the problem here. As long as the Controller return html data, the best way is to modify return type (or even better, add new controller to return json data with the same logic as old controller, for backward compatibility). You said you cannot touch the back-end, so may be extent it?

Comment: Thank you @TrongHoang. I will probably will make a new controller